# Take value for selected checkbox in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I want to be able to select only one checkbox and when select that checkbox to take that value in function in controller.

**Controller**

```
$foldersArray = [Folder 1 , Folder 2, Folder 3....];

$selectedFolderName = function(){
   var folderName = 'folder name '
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <ui>
    <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
       <label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="folder" ng-click=selectedFolderName()"/>{{folder}}</label>
   </li>
  </ui>
</div>
```

**Edit with radio button**

I tried with radio button something like this:

```
<div class="radio">
      <ui>
        <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
           <label><input type="radio" ng-model="folder.selected" ng-change=selectedFolderName(folder)"/>{{folder}}</label>
       </li>
      </ui>
    </div>
```

In controller

```
$selectedFolderName = function(folder){
       console.log(folder.selected);
    }
```

Like this all my radio buttons are selected...and nothing in console...

**EDIT ADDED PLUNKER**

Here is plunker: 
[plnkr.co/edit/xD0w4O1OC9xoKgYhXeMR?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/xD0w4O1OC9xoKgYhXeMR?p=preview)

Comment: You should use radio buttons if you want only one to be selectable.

Comment: @tymeJV i updated code that i try with radio buttons ...

Comment: Your updated code with radio buttons is still using checkboxes.

Comment: @tymeJV misstype i have type="radio" in my code, still don't work..

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?
also you should define your method as $scope.selectedFolderName in the controller.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xD0w4O1OC9xoKgYhXeMR?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

For fix this:

1. Remove attr ng-model
2. Change ng-change to ng-click
3. Remove selected atribute in selectedFolderName

Look this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foldersArray = ['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'];

  $scope.selectedFolderName = function(folder) {
    var folderName = folder;
    console.log(folderName);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="radio">
    <ui>
      <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-click="selectedFolderName(folder)">{{folder}}</label>
      </li>
    </ui>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foldersArray = ['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'];

      $scope.selectedFolderName = function(folder) {
        var folderName = folder;
        console.log(folderName);
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="radio">
        <ui>
          <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" ng-model="itemFolder" name="folder" ng-click="selectedFolderName(folder)">{{folder}}</label>
          </li>
        </ui>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: This is working, in console i get selected folder name. One thing that is bad is that if i click on Folder 1 and then on Folder2 both radio buttons are staying selected...

Comment: Where are we using this ng-model="itemFolder" in controller? It is working but i am confused how :P

Comment: You can remove and run new test. I put ng-model for controlling the selection of radio button

Comment: Oh i see so i just needed to add name="folder" in input attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/1wzsyeL9oA0w26Zznodj?p=preview

I've changed the ng-repeat [(example)](http://plnkr.co/edit/hfVRJ4pYZjNSQ5sOezn8?p=preview):

```
  <li ng-repeat="(folder,selected) in foldersArray">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="folder[]" ng-model="selectedFolder" ng-change="selectedFolderName(folder)">{{folder}}</label>
  </li>
```

Edit: 
You can manipulate the data as so:

```
$scope.foldersArray = ['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'];
$scope.foldersArrayNew = {};
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.foldersArray.length;i++) {
    $scope.foldersArrayNew[$scope.foldersArray[i]] = {selected: false};
}
$scope.foldersArray = $scope.foldersArrayNew;
```

Comment: Yeah this is working but in foldersArray i am getting data from service, can't change data...

Comment: @Bukic I added some changes so you'll be able to manipulate the data

Comment: @Alon For some reason this is working only when i click just for first time on folder and it is showing in console. If i click again on same folder it is not printing anything in console... Maybe it is m fault

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, for radio button to work as a group, you need to add `value` attribute which should be only string.

Excerpt from [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

> The value to which the ngModel expression should be set when selected. Note that value only supports string values, i.e. the scope model needs to be a string, too. Use ngValue if you need complex models (number, object, ...).

So modifying your example by adding `value` you can achieve the desired result.

```js
var app = angular.module("testapp", []);
app.controller("arrCntrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.foldersArray = ["Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3"];
    $scope.selectedFolder = {
        name: ""
    };
    $scope.selectedFolderName = function (folder) {
        console.log($scope.selectedFolder)
    }

    
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testapp">
    <div class="radio" ng-controller="arrCntrl">
        <ui>
            <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedFolder.name" value="{{folder}}" ng-change="selectedFolderName(selected)" />{{folder}}</label>
            </li>
        </ui>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    
</div>
```

Since you wanted check boxes to be selected only once at a time (which is not recommended as this is not their actual purpose).

Check boxes are functionally different (which allows to select more than one value), but we can mock the same functionality as radio buttons which will indeed require the use of javascript.

Below is an example of doing the same,

```js
var app = angular.module("testapp", []);
app.controller("arrCntrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.foldersArray = ["Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3"];


    $scope.selectedFolderNameChkBox = function(folder, isChecked) {

      var allChkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("folderChkBox");
      for (var i = 0; i < allChkBoxes.length; i++) {
        //console.log(angular.element(allChkBoxes[i]).scope.isChecked);
        if (allChkBoxes[i].value != folder) {
          allChkBoxes[i].checked = false;
        } else {
          if (allChkBoxes[i].checked) {
            console.log(allChkBoxes[i].value)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testapp">

  <div class="checkbox" ng-controller="arrCntrl">
    <ui>
      <li ng-repeat="folder in foldersArray">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="folderChkBox" value="{{folder}}" ng-click="selectedFolderNameChkBox(folder)" />{{folder}}</label>
      </li>
    </ui>
  </div>
</div>
```